# How to differentiate between files that need to be pulled in Git, and files that are committed locally and ready to be pushed

Tags: git, push, diff, pull

How do I determine which files in my local repository are committed  and ready to be pushed, and which files have been pushed by someone else in the meantime and need to be pulled, once you've already done a 'git fetch'?

For example:

```
git fetch
...

$ git diff --stat --staged origin/Release_Candidate

 AP4Configuration/ChangeLog.txt    | 3 +--
 AP4Configuration/appsettings.json | 3 +--
 Local5.txt                        | 1 -
 3 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
```

I staged and committed *appsettings.json* and *local5.txt* and they are ready to be pushed as part of the local commit(s), but *Changelog.txt* needs to be pulled from the repository on the server.

How can I tell that *Changelog.txt* is in a commit on the server that needs to be pulled, and *appsettings.json* and *local5.txt* are from a commit on my local machine that needs to be pushed?

I get the same result from:

```
git diff --stat --cached origin/Release_Candiate
git diff --stat --HEAD origin/Release_Candiate
```

Is there any way I can determine which files need to be pulled, and which ones are ready to push?

For example, I would like to see the files in the local commit(s) that will be pushed, without seeing the ones that are in the latest commit on the server ready to be pulled.

I am updating a GUI Git interface for my workplace, and the users need to see this information. Thanks.

Comment: Please consider rethinking how you see git. Git doesn't push or pull files

Comment: Staged files are not ready to be pushed.

Comment: OK, I've edited the question. I meant that my files were staged and committed to local repository. And I want to see the files in the commit that will be pushed, without seeing the ones that are in the latest commit on the server ready to be pulled.

Comment: @DerekMason Please provide some context on **why** you want to see this information.

Comment: I wrote a bespoke Git GUI system for my workplace to aid the staff work together using Git source-control (It needed to be bespoke because the off-the-shelf packages were not suitable). As part of the system we need to be able to see the files to pull, the files to push (obviously, we're pushing and pulling commits). But since we moved to a Release_Candidate branch (instead of master), the system is having difficulty differentiating from files in commits that should be pulled, and files in commits that will be pushed. So I am trying to break it down into Git commands that I can use.

Comment: "which files have been pushed by someone else in the meantime and need to be pulled (after a 'git fetch')" Without doing a `git fetch` first, how would it be possible to know this (even if the question were meaningful)?

Comment: I have done a 'git fetch'. Once this is done, the list in my example shows 'ChangeLog.txt', which is part of the repository that is to be pulled.
All I want to know is if there is any way to determine that this file is not part of my local repository changes that will be pushed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured out what I need to do.

After a 'git fetch', the following command shows both local and remote changes:

```
$ git diff --stat --cached origin/Release_Candidate

 AP4Configuration/ChangeLog.txt    | 3 ++-
 AP4Configuration/appsettings.json | 3 ++-
 Local5.txt                        | 1 +
 3 files changed, 5 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

But to see the file(s) that I myself modified, and that will be pushed as part of my local commits:

```
$ git diff --stat --merge-base origin/Release_Candidate

 AP4Configuration/appsettings.json | 3 ++-
 Local5.txt                        | 1 +
 2 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

This list does not show Changelog.txt. It now only shows the files I committed locally. Therefore I can see which files in the commits will be pushed, and which ones will need pulling from the server-side commits.

Answer (score 0):

There are no changes in your local repository that have been pushed by someone else unless you have done a `git fetch` (directly or via `git pull`). Those files are in a remote repository.

When you fetch the upstream changes with `git fetch`, the **remote** branch is updated to the most recent commit.

Your local changes are on the **local** branch which tracks the remote branch, and therefore you don't see those changes on this branch.

For instance, if the remote repository is called `origin` and the branch is `master`, then the remote branch is `origin/master`, and `master` refers to the local branch.

You can inspect the remote changes with `git log` and other tools. E.g. if the remote branch is called `origin/master`, you can `git log origin/master` to list the new changes you've picked up after `git fetch`.

To combine the two, you must either `rebase` or `merge`.

Under `git rebase`, all your local changes that you have committed are first stowed away somewhere, and then your branch is updated to match remote branch. Your changes are then cherry-picked back into your local branch, one by one. Automatic merging takes place, but conflicts may arise that you have to manually repair; there is a workflow for that whereby the rebase stops, leaving you with a situation where all the cherry-picked changes are staged, except for the conflicted files, which you must edit to remove conflict markers and then add to the stage with `git add`; then `git rebase --continue`.

Your local branch cannot be pushed (at least not without `--force`) to the remote repository unless it is based on the current remote branch (i.e. has the current commit of the remote branch as an ancestor). To push your change you have fetch, rebase and push. If the push is rejected because someone else pushed something new while you were rebasing, you must repeat fetch, rebase and push.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. However, I think I am having trouble explaining my question. In my example, I have staged and committed some files locally. Also, I have done a 'git fetch'. Once this is done, the list in my example also shows 'ChangeLog.txt', which is part of the repository that is to be pulled. All I want to know is if there is any way to determine that this file is not part of my local repository changes that will be pushed, i.e. it is from the repository on the server that first needs to be pulled. Thanks.

Comment: `Derek Mason` To answer the question "do I have changes to `ChangeLog.txt` in one of my unpublished commits", I would do any one of these thiings: do a `git diff origin/master ChangeLog.txt`. Or perhaps open up the graphical `gitk` and browse my branch.  View the log: `git log -p`.